# What is "public.rr_pending_changes" and why is taking up 9gigs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm running a rails 3 application with PostgreSQL 9.1 on AWS. The PostgreSQL setup has one master and a slave. We recently noticed our db backups were taking a long time and over 1gig compressed. After looking at a db backup locally, we noticed the table that takes up the most space is:

```
"public.rr_pending_changes"    8851 MB
```

The 2nd largest table is only 355 MB. Does anyone know what this `public.rr_pending_changes` table is if we really need it to take up that much space?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search suggests that `rr_pending_changes` is for rubyrep, a replication system.

Perhaps you had rubyrep in place, stopped using it, and didn't remove its triggers? Or maybe you think you're replicating but it actually isn't working?

Comment: Hi Craig, I don't use rubyrep, and do not have the gem installed. I've had to take over for an existing ops person and therefore can not be 100% sure we never used rubyrep. Is there a way to check? Are you this isn't is not apart of PostgreSQL replication?

Comment: @AnApprentice I am *absolutely certain* that it isn't a part of standard PostgreSQL replication. As for checking for rubyrep, I haven't used it myself, but since it's a trigger based system I'd check tables for triggers. They probably have `rr` or `rubyrep` in their names. Use `\d tablename` in `psql` to show triggers, or query the catalog for them. Have a look at the rubyrep documentation, too. I'd say someone installed rubyrep then never removed it properly.